# Graph Theory - globally minimal cut and its implications

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow

Given a weighted directed graph, we want to find the globally minimal cut - that is, a set of edges that if removed separate the graph in two halves and that have the minimal amount of total weight compared to any other such cut.

Now, although the following seems to work, I've been told that the reasoning is wrong. But quite frankly, I don't see how and I'm not sure about how certain he was:

Consider the sets of nodes `U,V` that are separated by the globally minimal cut (i.e. the s-t-cut, where `s in U, t in V`). Note: we don't care about the edges back from `V` to `U`.

For any `u in U, v in V`m the u-v-cut cannot be smaller than the `s-t-cut`, otherwise, the s-t-cut would not be (globally) minimal. For the same reason, no cut between two vertices in `u` or two vertices in `V` can be smaller.

On the other hand, the u-v-cut cannot be greater either, otherwise, it would need to include some edges `U->V` not part of the s-t-cut, which means the s-t-cut is no cut at all.

It is sufficient, therefore, to fix `s` arbitrarily and iterate over all other vertices `x`. `s` is either in `U`, then the s-x-cut corresponds to the global minimum if `x` is in `V`, or the x-s-cut does if `s` is in `V` and `x` is in `U`. If they are both part of the same set, the cut will be at least as great (but possibly greater) as the global minimum.

Therefore, we will eventually find the global minimum by calculating both, and keeping track of the minimum cut encountered so far.

It seemed to make sense to me. Am I wrong? And if so, why?

Comment: Suppose you assume that `s` is in `U` and `x` is in `V`. Why does it follow that the `s`-`x` cut corresponds to the global minimum? The global minimum cut would have to separate `s` _simultaneously_ from all vertices in `V` and may have nothing to do with the minimum `s`-`x` cut.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it. Could you make an example where this is not the case?

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you asked, but yes, by fixing a vertex s and computing all s-t and t-s min-cuts for all vertices t != s, you will eventually find a globally minimum cut. However, the runtime will be Ω(n * (time to compute minimum s-t cut)), which is not very good

Comment: Hm. Does this work as an example? Edges = {(s, a, 2), (s, b, 1), (a, b, 1), (b, a, 1), (a, c, 1), (b, c, 2)}. There are multiple global minimum cuts of weight 3, but the minimum cuts from `s` to each other vertex has weight either 1 or 2.

Comment: @TedHopp Ok nevermind my previous comment. So in your example, a globally minimum cut would be ({c}, {a,b,s}) of weight 0 (because there are no edges from c to any other vertex). But that cut is also a c-s cut of weight 0, so not a contradiction

Comment: Basically the weight of a cut (S, T) is the cumulative weight of edges (a, b) where a is in S and b is in T

Comment: Ah, crap. I missed that. Well, modify the example to make every edge undirected (or bi-directed, if you prefer).

Comment: @TedHopp Well then, the global min cut is 3 and the minimum s-t cut is 3 as well. Not sure where you got the 1/2 cut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation is that you're basically asking the following question:

> Can we find a global minimum cut by fixing an arbitrary vertex s and computing all s-t and t-s min cuts for all vertices t != s?

The answer is yes, and it's easy to prove: Consider a global min-cut (U, V) with value C. Then either s is in U or s is in V.

**Case 1**: s is in U. By definition of a minimum cut we have V != {}, so there is a vertex t in V. Then (U, V) is a valid s-t cut, so the minimum s-t cut will have value at most C

**Case 2**: s is in V. Then there exists a vertex t in U and the same argument as above holds for the minimum t-s cut

This algorithm is described for example [in Chapter 6.4 of these MIT lecture notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/flowscuts.pdf).

Comment: My question is actually **why** we can do that. The MIT lecture notes - thanks for the link - simply state *that* we can do it but not why. I kind of fail to see the difference to what I wrote, so I'll just ask: wlog assume s is in U. Does that imply that any minimal u-v-cut where u is in U and v is in V must have value C or not? And why?

Comment: "Does that imply that any minimal u-v-cut where u is in U and v is in V must have value C or not" Yes it does. Because (U, V) is a valid u-v cut by the definition of s-t cuts and it has value C